# How to solve the error Object is of type unknown with VueStripe

Tags: typescript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I imported the StripeCheckout component in my Vue3 App but I have an error with my submit method.

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. I imported the StripeCheckout Component.
2. I added the  part
3. I added all the data and the submit method.
4. I have this error : Object is of type 'unknown' on my this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout() method.

**Here is my view code**

```
<template>
<div class="section form-degustation-section">
    <div class="mycontain form-degustation-contain">
        <a href="/degustations">retrouner aux calendrier des soirées</a>
        <div class="soiree-text-presentation-contain">
            <h1>Titre de l'événement</h1>
            <p>Description de l'événement. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat. Aenean faucibus nibh et justo cursus id rutrum lorem imperdiet. Nunc ut sem vitae risus tristique posuere.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="soiree-form-contain">
            <h2>Formulaire de réservation</h2>
            <div class="w-form">
                <div id="wf-form-soirees-degustation" name="wf-form-soirees-degustation" data-name="soirees degustation" action="https://natureetvins.foxycart.com/cart" method="post">
                    <label for="name">Nom et prénom</label>
                    <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="name" data-name="Name" placeholder="Ecrivez votre nom et prénom" id="name" data-kwimpalastatus="alive" data-kwimpalaid="1626170679038-0">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="email" data-name="Email" placeholder="Ecrivez votre adresse email" id="email" required="" data-kwimpalastatus="alive" data-kwimpalaid="1626170679038-1">
                    <label for="email-2">Téléphone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="field" data-name="Field" placeholder="Ecrivez votre numéro de téléphone" id="field" required="" data-kwimpalastatus="alive" data-kwimpalaid="1626170679038-2">
                    <label for="quantity">Quantité</label>
                    <input type="number" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="quantity" data-name="quantity" placeholder="Combien de places voulez vous acheter ?" id="quantity" required="" min="1">
                    <div class="w-embed">
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Name">
                        <input type="hidden" name="prix" value="Prix">
                        <input type="hidden" name="image" value="Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="event-cta-contain">
            <div>
              <stripe-checkout
                :ref="checkoutRef"
                mode="payment"
                :pk="publishableKey"
                :line-items="lineItems"
                :success-url="successURL"
                :cancel-url="cancelURL"
                @loading="(v) => (loading = v)"
              />
              <button @click="submit" class="cta-button w-button">Payer</button>
            </div>
          </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>




<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import { StripeCheckout } from "@vue-stripe/vue-stripe";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    StripeCheckout,
  },
  data() {
    this.publishableKey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
    return {
      degustation: {},
      id_product: this.$route.params.id as string,
      loading: false,
      lineItems: [
        {
          price: "",
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      successURL: "http://google.fr",
      cancelURL: "http://google.fr",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/degustations/${this.id_product}`)
      .then((response) => (this.degustation = response.data));
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout()
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

**Screenshots of the error**

[image]

Is this a problem with vue3 or TypeScript ?

Comment: Could you try to remove `lang="ts"` in the `<script>` tag to see if it works?

Comment: My project is entierrely in TypeScript so no it's not working

Comment: Could it be because of the typo `ref="checkoutRef"`? Notice that there is no `:` before `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the example code in the [documentation](https://vuestripe.com/stripe-checkout/one-time-payment), I think the error is how you declare your `checkoutRef` in your `<stripe-checkout>` tag. The correct one should be:

```html
<stripe-checkout
  ref="checkoutRef"
  mode="payment"
  :pk="publishableKey"
  :line-items="lineItems"
  :success-url="successURL"
  :cancel-url="cancelURL"
  @loading="(v) => (loading = v)"
/>
```

Notice that there is no `:` before `ref`.

If it still doesn't work, then I guess the problem is Vue 3. As mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vue-stripe/vue-stripe/issues/148), `vue-stripe` doesn't support Vue 3 yet.

If using Vue 3 is a must, maybe an alternative library should be considered, such as [vue-use-stripe](https://github.com/frandiox/vue-use-stripe).

Comment: Same thing without the :

Comment: Yes I switched to vue2 but I still have errors : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68364670/how-to-use-vuestripe-on-vue2-project